# PHP User search, table with multiple elements

Tags: php, mysql

Basically I have a table made more or less like this:

```
name
John

surname

Mariani

address
via I do not know 12

Characteristics
Tall, Thin, Blue Eyes, Long Hair, Brown Hair
```

Now the problem is that I have created separate pages, such as: Red Hair; hair;

(Now of course it is a stupid example, but it is to make it clear)

And I made sure to appear in these pages the users with those characteristics. So if you click on Red Hair out all users with red hair etc.

This is the script used:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE characteristics LIKE '%$search%' ORDER BY name");
```

The problem is that in this way, even if the user has among its characteristics, such as only the characteristics Hair, also appears on the page Red Hair because obviously in the query using LIKE, so I wanted to know how to make this does not happen; how can I distinguish well the various features? Obviously without creating other fields in the table.

Answer (score 0):

the answer is:

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE characteristics LIKE '%$%' ORDER BY name");

to show you just what you want